# Cannot generate vcxproj file in the gn tutorial hello_world

Tags: chromium, gn

I run

```
gn gen out/mybuild --args="is_component_build=true is_debug=true enable_nacl=false remove_webcore_debug_symbols=true" --ide=vs --filters=//tools/gn
ninja -C out/mybuild hello_world
```

but no hellow_world.vcxproj generated.